# ADB2C with authentication/logout not working in Blazor

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, blazor, blazor-client-side

When using ADB2C for authentication in a Blazor Webassembly project, the authentication/logout seems to log out and shows a page with the request to close all browsers. 
Anyway if the user just uses the back button in the browser she/he is still able to access the contents and is treated as still loged-on.
So, how to get a real logout?

Comment: Does the AuthenticationState object still contain the data of the logged out user ?

Comment: yes, the LoginDisplay still shows the user name and the logout link

Comment: And when you navigate out of the app space, and then click the back button. .. Are you still able to access data as before ?

Comment: yes seems the logout is not finished?

Answer (score 2):

**While directing the user to the `end_session_endpoint` will clear some of the user's single sign-on state with Azure AD B2C,** it will not sign the user out of the user's social identity provider (IDP) session. If the user selects the same IDP during a subsequent sign-in, they will be reauthenticated, without entering their credentials. If a user wants to sign out of your B2C application, it does not necessarily mean they want to sign out of their Facebook account entirely. However, in the case of local accounts, the user's session will be ended properly.

To sign out the user, redirect the user to the end_session endpoint that is listed in the OpenID Connect metadata document([example](https://login.microsoftonline.com/fabrikamb2c.onmicrosoft.com/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration?p=b2c_1_sign_in)) :

```
GET https://{tenant}.b2clogin.com/{tenant}.onmicrosoft.com/{policy}/oauth2/v2.0/logout?post_logout_redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fjwt.ms%2F
```

Reference: [Azure Active Directory B2C: Web sign-in with OpenID Connect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-oidc#send-a-sign-out-request)

Comment: In the case of the `IDP` scenario, it would be something like this: 1. initiate logout, 2. logout out of ADB2C (which is done by the library mainly), 3. redirect user to the `end_session_endpoint` of the `IDP`. This makes sense, but then in my case, the user is stuck there. After it signs out of the `IDP` it is left with a "successfully signed out"